# How to find exact datasheet of an Op-Amp from the IC markings?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm trying to understand Op-Amps and reading datasheets. I have an Op-Amp which has the following marked on the IC:

---

741D
JRC
8001

---

When I search on the web for 741D I find many different variants such as 741. Is 741D and 741 is the same? Is JRC the manufacturer name? What does 8001 stand for?

Is anything with 741 the same regardless of A B C D at the end of it and manufacturer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

741D is a variant of the 741, you would need to read the manufacturer's own datasheet to find what the D signifies, but it is probably the package (e.g. plastic 8-pin DIP as opposed to ceramic DIP or SOIC).

However there is a chance that it is a variant in supply voltage range or some other parameter like input offset voltage, so that is worth checking if performance is critical. But for most parameters, any 741 datasheet will do including LM741 or the original uA741 if you can find it.

And JRC is a well known manufacturer so their databook or website would be the place to start. A little searching shows some company reorganisation so [this](http://www.njr.com/) is the site you need for their semiconductors, rather than [the obvious one](http://www.jrc.co.jp/eng/). Searching that page for 741 yields several hits including [this](http://semicon.njr.co.jp/eng/product/opamp/NJM741.html): where you can download a [datasheet](http://semicon.njr.co.jp/eng/PDF/NJM741_E.pdf). And that shows a DIP - NJM741D and a SOIC - NJM741M.

8001 is most likely to be a date code : week 1 of 1980. That would be before the reorganisation hence the manufacturer is JRC rather than NJM.

Comment: Does this one function the same way with mine? http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf ? It is also called 741.

Comment: edited ... basically yes

Answer (score 0):

Brian gave an excellent answer for this particular part.

However, in general there's no really good way to do what you're asking. Historically there were books that tabulated the markings on parts from different companies. Nowadays you can try an internet search on the markings, but I find that only occasionally works.

When a search fails, you have to guess what the part is, and then look through the datasheets for that part from different manufacturers to find one who marks the part the way you're looking for.

If you're lucky there will be a manufacturer's logo or initials marked on the part and that will narrow down the search considerably. Or give you enough information to call the manufacturer's applications department and ask which part is marked that way.